# TypeORM: When inserting new entity error occurs: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: typeorm

I'm using PostgreSQL and TypeORM. My create table is:

```
CREATE TABLE "my_table"("id" uuid NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_my_table PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

My entity class definition is:

```
import { Entity, Generated, PrimaryColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('my_table')
export class MyTable {
    @PrimaryColumn({ type: 'uuid' })
    @Generated('uuid')
    id!: string;
}
```

When I run

```
entityManager.getRepository(MyTable).save({});
```

I got the error message:

```
(node:85) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: QueryFailedError: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

So it seems that id is not generated. This is odd, because this is working when other entitys are saved in the application.

What could be problem?? I have simplified the real situation for testing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I generated the uuid manually and my entity is:

```
@Entity('my_table')
export class MyTable {    
    @PrimaryColumn({ type: 'uuid' })
    id!: string;
}
```

This is working.

Comment: You should be using `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error here when my id field is set to null. It may happen when transforming DTOs into Entities.
If I set the id to undefined, it works.